# Why do __try blocks reduce speed of my program?

Tags: c++, exception

I have been researching whether the `__try`/`__except` construct is fast enough for my use, and encountered a strange result.

I was surprised to find that calling a function inside a `__try` block is twice as fast as calling it on its own.

Why is this?

---

```
 #include <iostream>


 using namespace std;

 //addiitonal statndart includes
 #include <windows.h>

 void function()
 {
    int a=0;
        for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<1000000;j++)
            {
                if(0==i*j % 2)
                    a++;
                else
                    a--;
            }
cout << a<< endl;
 }
 //you can make 0 for test wihtout try
 #define USE_TRY 1

 int main()
 {

DWORD time = 0;
time =timeGetTime();

#if USE_TRY
    __try{
        function();
    }
    __except(1)
    {
        cout <<"   exception handled"<< endl;
    }
#else
    function();
#endif

time =timeGetTime()-time;

cout<<"time = "<<time<<endl;

 }
```

Comment: You didn't give your compiler version, optimization settings, and you used code with all kinds of optimization opportunities.  Then you only ran the function once.  And you're trying to benchmark?  `timeGetTime` is a horrible choice for timing code anyway, not nearly precise enough.

Comment: And even if we grant you that your code is a sound benchmark (it's not), I get no statistically significant differences at all, so the question is moot.

Comment: i compiled with visual studio 2008(actually 9.0.21022.8 version) and all other things by default. about timeGetTime() agreed but i think it is enough to see two time difference

Comment: @Feruzbek: Have you ran the test *multiple* times? Can you post what results you get into your question? I ask because I ran your code with `USE_TRY == 1` and `USE_TRY == 0` and both give me *the exact same times*. I get times that consistently hover between `3340-3350` for both versions. Until you post your results and provide *exact details* of the environment your claim that `__try` blocks are faster have no teeth.

Comment: 4 times without __try()  3510,3516,3568,3419   and with __try 1782,1792,1739,1732

Comment: The problem seems to be more complex. On my VS2010 in debug build I get times about 3200ms per run no matter which define I use. On a release build it changes to be around 2400ms for the non __try version to 1200ms for the __try version. BTW: I changed the timing to QueryPerformanceCounter as it is more reliable.

Comment: i forgot i compiled on release mode

Comment: The OP is framed pretty badly, but if the times listed by Feruzbek and mkaes are accurate then there is a genuine question here.

Comment: is there any genius that can answer to my question instead of correcting my English in the world

Answer (score 0):

While asking the question you probably mean you want to use `__try`/`__except` instead of `try`/`catch`.

Whether `__try`/`__except` works faster or slower than `try`/`catch` is unimportant because,
`__try` / `__except` is for catching **[SEH (windows generated errors)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** not for catching general exceptions.

For the standard C++ code you write you should always use `try`/ `catch` and not `__try` / `__except`.

`try`/`catch` is what the C++ standard specifies for handling general C++ exceptions.